Custom Sitecore item delete handler
I need to execute a logic before the Sitecore item deletion event or before Sitecore shows delete warning. I am trying
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
    <events>
    <event name="item:deleting" >
      <handler type="PH.Foundation.Extensions.Pipelines.CustomDeleteHandler, PH.Foundation.Extensions" method="OnItemDeleting" "/>
      
    </event>
    </events>
</sitecore>

but it executes after the Sitecore delete warning. How can I execute it before the delete warning or how can I edit the processor where sitecore shows a delete warning


In order to achive this you can patch your implementation for the custom processor before the below pipeline.
<configuration>
 <sitecore>
   <processors>
    <uiDeleteItems>
       <processor type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DeleteItems,Sitecore.Kernel" method="CheckPermissions" mode="on"/>
    </uiDeleteItems>
   </processors>
 </sitecore>
</configuration>

This pipeline is responsble for triggering Delete confirmation message. You can create a custom processor and patch it above the DeleteItems processor under the uiDeleteItems pipeline as below.
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
    <sitecore>
       <processors>
            <uiDeleteItems>
                <processor patch:before="*[@method='CheckPermissions' and @type='Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DeleteItems,Sitecore.Kernel']" mode="on" type="{{Custom_ProcessorClass}}" method="{{Custom_MethodName}}" />
            </uiDeleteItems>
       </processors>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>

Hope this helps!!!

i have used this and it looks as expected in show config but when I try to delete any item it gives error
System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException
Message: Parameter count mismatch.
My class and method is as below
public class CustomDeleteHandler
{
public void OnItemDeleting(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
Item item = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;}}

@Vinesh you need to change the code as well.. It will not use the event handler code..Check the Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DeleteItems class inside Sitecore.Kernel dll there you will get to know how to read the cuurent item parameter inside the CheckPermissions method. Let me know in case you have any doubts

Thanks for your help, It's working now

Great @Vinesh!!!
